# JMagick.dll for 64 bit processor

Tags: java, image, java-native-interface, jmagick

I am trying to run a program to call C++ libraries in ImageMagick using jmagick interface (JNI) from a java program. But I am getting following exception

---

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\jmagick.dll:
>   Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD
>   64-bit platform

---

I tried to search for jmagick.dll for 64 bit processors but couldn't find any. 
Could anybody suggest any solution or show me the path if 64 bit dll is available?

Thanks,

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I want to try this API to convert ant file to bitmap image. It will be helpful if you can suggest anything. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Remove your 64 bits JDK and install a 32 bits JDK. Final users will need a 32 bits JVM.

It's about the same thing when you want to develop with Java ME on a 64 bits processor.

---

**Resources :**

- [JMagic mailing list - Last mail about 64 bit dll](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4C1B9661.7090801%40schild.ws&forum_name=jmagick-users)

**On the same topic :**

- [Convert 32 bit dll to 64 bit dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944962/convert-32-bit-dll-to-64-bit-dll)